# VSCode How do I automatically stop my debugger when I finish running a script via launch.json

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have the current launch.json configuration:

```
{
  "command": "cd api && npm run test ${file}",
  "name": "Test current file",
  "request": "launch",
  "type": "node-terminal"
}
```

When I run this command, vscode successfully runs the script in debug mode.
After the script finished running, I get the output "Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...".
[image].
After the test is done I would like the terminal to automatically close but it doesn't happen.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean with "I would like the terminal to automatically close" ? The command is correctly closing the process.

Comment: @radar155 The terminal stays open and therefor the debugger doesn't disconnect even though the test already finished running.